# How to disable Disk Space Warning message in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I am creating installer using Inno Setup. I have calculated available disk space using function `GetSpaceOnDisk`. I am displaying error message if available disk space is not enough, and then installer will not continue.

But before my error message displays, Inno Setup Disk space warning is shown with Yes/No option. How can I disable this warning?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, since the check is hard-coded. The only possible workaround would be to lie to the installer about the amount of space you actually require. However, it is inadvisable to transform this space check into a fatal error. You have no way of knowing exactly how much space your install is going to require. You might be doing a reinstall on top of an existing installation, in which case many of the components will already be installed and therefore will not require free space. If the user wants to try and install anyway, just let them. You've already warned them.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

It seems there is noway to disbale it. Can i get to know whether user pressed yes or no?

Comment: Why do you need your own warning?

Comment: What page is this about? Select destination or components?

Comment: Thus page is about select destination. If path provided by user does not have sufficient free space then installer should not continue, that was my requirement. I have handled NextButtonClick and displayed warning in the code, but my warning appeared after Inno warning. So either i should disable the inno warning or inno warning should not provide yes/no button, I was serching whether i can use either of the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot disable the check, nor change the buttons.

---

What you can do, is to revert a meaning of a question in the message by overriding the default text using `[Messages]` section, to say something like:

> Do you want to cancel installation?

If the user presses *No*, the installer stays on the *Select Destination Location* page. If the user presses *Yes*, the `NextButtonClick(wpSelectDir)` gets called. There you repeat the check for the disk space (to distinguish the call from a basic scenario, with no warning), and if there's not enough space, you abort the installer forcefully.

```
[Messages]
DiskSpaceWarning=Setup requires at least %1 KB of free space to install, but the selected drive only has %2 KB available.%n%nDo you want to cancel installation?
```

```pascal
[Code]

function NotEnoughSpace: Boolean;
begin
  Result := { Check disk space };
end;

procedure ExitProcess(exitCode:integer);
  external 'ExitProcess@kernel32.dll stdcall';
  
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectDir then
  begin
    if NotEnoughSpace then
    begin
      ExitProcess(0);
    end; 
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

---

The ultimate solution is to re-implement the *Select Destination Location* page. It's not that difficult. It's just one edit box and one button.